# Proving that a function is not an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

[image]

I have this function here that I need to prove is not an inner product.

I've been able to use the first three axioms (symmetry, additivity and homogeneity), which the function has satisfied, but I'm not sure how to go about using the positivity axiom to prove that it is not an inner product space.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The $-$ sign is a problem for positivity. Exploit it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: The inner product of a vector with itself has to be non-negative. But if there's a $-$ sign in the inner product, (and you know it is not an inner product) then the best way to find a counterexample is to increase the term which has the $-$ sign (which is $z_1z_2$) and minimize the positive terms. Once you see this, the vector $(0,0,-1,0)$ is a problem : its inner product with itself has to be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(0,0,1,0)$ and compute $\langle v,v\rangle.$